# NHiberate session.Get() gets the cached entity. How to get the latest entity from the DB?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-caches

I'm using the CQRS pattern to get the data from the DB using NHibernate.

Here is the CommittingTransactionCommandHandler which calls the UpdateProductHandler

```
class CommittingTransactionCommandHandler
{
    private readonly ISession session;
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _inner; //Generic Command Handlers

    public CommittingTransactionCommandHandler(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public async Task Execute(TCommand command)
    {
        using (var txn = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Unspecified))
        {
            try
            {
                await _inner.Update(command); // This calls the UpdateProducthandler's Update method
                txn.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Command Handler for the Update.

```
class UpdateProductHandler : ICommand
{
    private readonly ISession session;
    public UpdateProductHandler(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public async Task Update(int id, ProductIdentity productIdentity)
    {
        var product = session.Get(id);
        product.Update(productIdentity);
    }
}
```

Here is the Query Handler for the Get

```
class GetProductHandler
{
    private readonly ISession session;
    public GetProductHandler(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public async Task<Product> Get(int id)
    {
        var product = session.Get(id);
        if (product == null)
            throw new Exception("Entity not found");
        return Task.FromResult(product);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Product entity

```
class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int? Version { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Update(ProductIdentity productIdentity)
    {
        Name = productIdentity.Name;
        Description = productIdentity.Description;
    }
}
```

> The flow is
>
> **CommittingTransactionCommandHandler** is a generic command handler. This is called from the API, which internally invokes the **UpdateProductHandler**. The *transaction is opened in this and committed here*.

The scenario is that

1. I get a Product from the DB using the **GetProductHandler**. *(In this case, the version number of the Product is 10.)*
2. I'm updating the Product using the **UpdateProductHandler** and commits the session which is under the transaction. *(Here version number of the Product is 11)*
3. Immediately after the Update Product, I query the same Product using the **GetProductHandler** and loads it in the Edit mode in the UI. *(But the Product fetched using the GetProductHandler has a version number 10 and not 11.)*
4. Here is the issue, instead of getting the latest update from the DB, the above **GetProductHandler**, gets the previous state of the object.(Found using the version number)
5. Now, if I try to update the Product, I get a ***Stale Object State Exception*** since the version number is 10 which is not the latest version of the Product.

> I've tried with session.Refresh(product) but all in vain as it affects the other transactions.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Ignore the async part. Just a reference I gave you. I could see the update happening in the DB when I query it. But the record got from the `Get` handler was the previous version of the record and not the latest.

Comment: `public async Task Update()` is a generic definition we've for the command handlers.

Answer (score 2):

As [Ayende](https://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) explains, `Get` will NOT *always* hit the database. It will only hit the database if entity not found in first level cache.

You have not explained how you are updating the entity; what is inside `product.Update` method. If you are updating using API that does not update underlying first level cache (SQL/HQL/Linq), then the problem you stated in question is obvious. In that case,

- You load entity in session cache using `Get` (Version 10). This hits the database.
- Then, you call `Update` (database hit) which will not update the first level cache (Version changed to 11 in database; NOT in cache).
- Then you call `Get` again. NHibernate looks if entity is already loaded in session cache. Yes; it is (Version 10). It just returns it. No database hit.

**Solution 1:**

Not sure why that `Update` method is needed. You can directly update the entity like below:

```
public async Task Update(int id, ProductIdentity productIdentity)
{
    var product = session.Get(id);
    product.Version = 11;
    //Update other properties here
    ...
    ...
    //That's it. You are already calling `Flush` somewhere somehow
}
```

**Solution 2:**

As Ayende NOT recommended (and I am not recommending either), don't use `Get` and write a query that will hit the database. Use Linq/HQL/SQL API instead.

> ```
> select customer from s.Linq<Customer>()
> where customer.Id = customerId
> select customer
> ).FirstOrDefault();
> ```
>
> Every time that I see something like that, I wince a little inside. The reason for that is quite simple. This is doing a query by primary key. The key word here is a query.
>
> This means that we have to hit the database in order to get a result for this query. Unless you are using the query cache (which by default you won’t), this force a query on the database, bypassing both the first level identity map and the second level cache.
>
> Get  and Load are here for a reason, they provide a way to get an entity by primary key. That is important for several aspects, most importantly, it means that NHibernate can apply quite a few optimizations for this process.